# Trick-taking card game, where you aim to reach zero points?

Tags: identify-this-game

My family has been playing this card game for years but no one knows what it is called.

You start by dealing out 5 cards to everyone, then flip the next card, which marks the trump suit. The dealer can pick up that card and discard one from his hand face down. Then you go around the table and say if you are in or out, but the dealer has to be in.

Scoring: you start with 21 points and every trick lowers your points. If you get skunked you get 5 points added to your score. You want to get to exactly zero.

What is the name of this game?

Answer (score 4):

This sounds like a [trick taking](http://www.pagat.com/class/trick.html) game in the [Rams group](http://www.pagat.com/rams/).

> **Rams group:** in these games players have the opportunity to drop out after seeing their hands, but anyone who stays in and fails to make their quota of tricks suffers a penalty.

None of these seem to match the rules you state exactly.

[Raub](http://www.pagat.com/rams/raub.html) starts at 21, with players trying to get to 0 points. But, it is played with 4 cards, when you fail to score a trick you add +4.

[Loo:](http://www.davidparlett.co.uk/histocs/loo.html) doesn't have the starting total, with players winning shares of the pot for the proportion of tricks they take, with players that take none having to pay into the pot.

[Bourre:](http://www.pagat.com/rams/boure.html#introduction) also isn't a perfect fit. It also has a pot like Loo, has players who fail to take tricks paying into the pot. It does have the first revealed card to indicate trump.

Answer (score -1):

My parents played this game back in the day and they called it donut cause of the circle around the skunk when players go up 5 points

Answer (score -3):

My family always called it "Cut Throat".  Apparently it's also known as "Cut throat Euchre" or "Club Buck Euchre".

Comment: It looks like you just copied a portion of the question. You can [edit] your answer to include more helpful information instead of just repeating the question.